# SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP wait type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have one problem. SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS is in suspended state and starttime is not refreshed. I execute procedure SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS manually and it is working normally. Some forums say its normal. But monitoring tool retrieve high query time.

Version of SQL Server as below:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-CU9) (KB4037357) - 13.0.2216.0 (X64)   Nov  9 2017 14:24:19   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

How can I fix it? [image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

> SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS is in suspended state and starttime is not refreshed.

That's correct. It runs in an infinite loop and has a `SLEEP` wait type added to the end of it when it is waiting to run again. This is all normal, you don't have any problems.

Comment: If it's correct why other server this problem doesn't happened? We see it as a zabbix problem. Query run time is high.

Comment: @natiqrzazade "*Query run time is high*" - Which query?...the one for `SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS` or other queries on your server?

Comment: @J.D. , SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS only is run. Monitoring return alert due to SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS

Comment: @natiqrzazade turn off that alert, it's useless.

Comment: If I turn off this alert in that case I can't identify other long time running queries in other servers.

Comment: There's no point in having any alert for this. Your issue is that a monitoring tool isn't taking into account how features actually work. The monitoring tool is wrong. Period.

Comment: @natiqrzazade what I mean is that you should turn off the specific alert for this background task stored procedure.